# Open multiple 'txt 'in a folder in Java

Tags: java, file, java-8, java-stream

In Java 8 I need to read and save several text files that are in a folder. With several I mean 2000. How should I do it?
I can open the folder as follows:

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("home\path"))) {
    paths
       .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
       .collect(Collectors.toList())
       .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This also prints the location of the files. I only did it to know I could get to the folder.

Can read the files as described below. But how do I get the name of all 2000 files  I want?

```
File encyptFile=new File("file1.txt");
System.out.println(encyptFile.canRead());
```

Comment: What is the type of file involved?

Comment: It's _txt_ @JoeC

Comment: collecting into a list  `.collect(Collectors.toList())`  before invoking `forEach` is superfluous. `paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(System.out::println);` would be the better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by calling `Path::getFileName` method, like this:

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("home\path"))) {
paths
   .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
   .map(Path::getFileName)
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
   .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

If you also need some extension verification, you can add filter by extension for the file name like this `path.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt")`

Example:

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("home\path"))) {
paths
   .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
   .filter(path -> path.toString().toLowerCase().endsWith(".txt"))
   .map(Path::getFileName)
   .collect(Collectors.toList())
   .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: thx. You can help me to open and save the data that are inside these files? @Aleksandr Podkutin

Comment: @Walt057 NP, yes sure. You can add any logic to the `forEach` method and write some data to file. Regarding writing data, you can do it like this: https://www.baeldung.com/java-write-to-file

Comment: collecting into a list  `.collect(Collectors.toList())`  before invoking `forEach` is superfluous.

Comment: @Aomine I agree with you, just want to remind, that the main question was about getting the file name and because of that I've just reused examples from Walt057